# chrome, opera, firefox, console not show error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

It happen recently, I found all my browser, chrome, opera, firefox, console not show error anymore, just silently stop js script.

```
console.log(' undefined variable should show error ', aa, bb)
```

Before, console, will show error:  'aa' is undefined, but now, nothing show on console, I have latest version opera is v66.0.x,  chronm is v79.0.x

Edit 1/29/2020

I kind of find the problem. If I put

```
         console.log(' undefined variable should show error ', aa, bb)
```

in the regular place, browser does output:

```
              Uncaught ReferenceError: aa is not defined
```

However, if I put the same code in fetch stream,  even this code was implemented, was run into, browser, console will NOT show any error message, just stop run js script SILENTLY !

```
                  // ----- fetch.stream api -----
                  fetch(_url_decoded)
                             // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
                      .then(response => response.body)
                      .then(rs => {

                                  //console.log('test ', uuuu)


                                  const reader = rs.getReader();

                                  return new ReadableStream({


                                    async start(controller) {




                                            while (true) {


                                                          const { done, value } = await reader.read();

                                                          // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
                                                          if (done) {


                                                                  console.log('test ', uuuu)
```

I test the case on all latest version of firefox, chrome, opera, all the same silence stop without output any error message!!!

```
  Who can tell me why?
```

Comment: Maybe you have some `.catch()` handler on the promise?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem, it is complicated to explain, I don't know where is problem.

[This is working code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Examples):   console will report error on any undefined variable

```
        fetch("https://www.example.org/").then((response) => {
               const reader = response.body.getReader();
                const stream = new ReadableStream({
                    start(controller) {
                            // The following function handles each data chunk
                              function push() {
    // "done" is a Boolean and value a "Uint8Array"
    reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
      // Is there no more data to read?
      if (done) {
        // Tell the browser that we have finished sending data
        controller.close();
        return;
      }

      // Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller
      controller.enqueue(value);
      push();
    });
  };

  push();
}
});

  return new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html" } });
});
```

My original code have problem, console will not report error on any undefined varible, just quietly stop js engine.

```
                 fetch(_url_decoded)
                             // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
                      .then(response => response.body)
                      .then(rs => {

                                  // will catch error at below catch block
                                  // console.log('test ', uuuu)


                                  const reader = rs.getReader();

                                  return new ReadableStream({


                                    async start(controller) {

                                                                // will not show error undefined in console.  
                                                                //console.log('test ', uuuu) 


                                            while (true) {


                                                          const { done, value } = await reader.read();




                                                          // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
                                                          if (done) {

                                                                    break;   // or,  return, depends on, here use while loop, so use break. if it is recursive function "processText()",then use 'return' here.
                                                          }




                                                          // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
                                                          controller.enqueue(value);

                                            } //while




                                            // after 'done' , break the while loop, come here to Close the stream

                                            controller.close();
                                            reader.releaseLock();

                                            return;
                                    } // start




                                  }) // ReadableStream



                    })// then   
                    .catch((error) => {
                      console.error('fetch Error -> :', error);
                    });
```